# Do you know of a Xpages Extension Library Control for dropdown menus?

Tags: xpages

I see a "menu dropdown" type control in one of the examples of the OneUI application Framework v2.1. [see here](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/examples.htm?content=interactive.htm&theme=green)

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/examples.htm?content=interactive.htm&theme=green

If you hover over the links at the top of the interactive demo like "people" and "communities" a dropdown menu appears. I would love to use this control if it exists rather than creating one.

Thanks in advance for any info.

Elijah Lapson

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you use the Application Layout control and add a container node with children to the Utility Links or Application Links section, you will get a drop down. Here's an example:

```
<xe:basicContainerNode label="Container 1">
    <xe:this.children>
        <xe:basicLeafNode label="Link 1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
        <xe:basicLeafNode label="Link 2"></xe:basicLeafNode>
    </xe:this.children>
</xe:basicContainerNode>
```

It does not look exactly like the one in the UI documentation, however:

[image]

Comment: This also applies to the placebar actions: leaf nodes display as buttons, container nodes with leaf children create a dropdown menu.